# How to generate components with each value from a JSON file in React?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

I'm trying to implement something similar to Angular's `ngFor` directive in ReactJS. I've seen examples with `map` but I'm still not sure how to implement it correctly.

To provide more context; I need to build a grid with each square having the value of a letter read from a JSON file; I've built a component for each square, so it looks like this

```
class Square extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="square">
                {this.props.letters.board.map((letter) => <span>{letter}</span>)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This `letters` prop would be the JSON file I need to read, this is mostly what I'm not sure if I'm doing correctly:

```
function App() {
  let letters = require('./test-board-2.json');
  console.log(letters);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="letters">
          <Square letters={letters}/>
        </div>
        <div className="controls">
          <Clear />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Am I actually reading the JSON file in a adequate manner? I actually get the `console.log` just fine but what I get rendered is just one square with all the values of the json file, instead of one square for each value.

This is what the json file looks like:

```
{
    "board": [
        "L",
        "I",
        "S",
        "T",
        "O",
        "F",
        "A",
        "T",
        "S",
        "T",
        "R",
        "S",
        "O",
        "R",
        "A",
        "Y"
    ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated, I mostly have an Angular background, and I'm just starting learning React.

Comment: what is the css for `square` ?

Comment: @saurabh its not relevant really, is literally just an orange square with the letter inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're only seeing one Square is because you are passing in the whole JSON object into your `<Square />` component and then looping through the array inside of Square.

What you should be doing is looping through the array outside of the `Square` component, and rendering a Square component for each element of the array, like so:

```
function App() {
  let letters = require('./test-board-2.json');
  console.log(letters);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="letters">
          {letters.board.map(letter => <Square letter={letter}/>)}
        </div>
        <div className="controls">
          <Clear />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now, you can just use the `letter` prop inside of your `<Square />` component, like so:

```
function Square() {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="square">
        <span>{this.props.letter}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Now it looks really obvious, worked like a charm... If you don't mind me asking, is the method I'm using to read the json file okay? or should I be doing it some other way?

Comment: I recommend that you be consistent and use `import` over `require`. So you could do `import LettersJSON from './test-board-2.json'`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is what you read from your JSON file becomes an object. Try passing it to the square element by

```
<Square letters={letters.board}/>
```

Comment: I made this change and now I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: Nevermind, I actually get the same exact result as before

Comment: What is the output of your console.log

Comment: Its the whole object `board: Array(16)
0: "L"
1: "I"
2: "S"
3: "T"
4: "O"
5: "F"
6: "A"
7: "T"
8: "S"
9: "T"
10: "R"
11: "S"
12: "O"
13: "R"
14: "A"
15: "Y"`